# finding wrong characters in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Since I am about to write a small php-script I like to call to get all the javascript for my page, this leads to strange error on client side. The script does actually use an configuration xml-file and some xsl-stylesheets to generate an large Javascript string. Sometimes it happens that I get an 'unterminated String literal' error, sometimes an error rises that says: 'An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable', just after the javascript executes an document.write operation.
Are there any resources, or is there any tutorial, just something that reveals about the traps of running into such problems when copying a bunch of javscript files into one String or file?

greetings philipp

EDIT::
the following error:

[image: the error message]

is thrown in an webpage that is delivered with content-type: 'application/xhtml+xml'. The actual generated Javascript looks like this:

[source code generated](http://pastebin.com/8V302mz9)

The script itself runs until the first document.write command is triggered.

Comment: Perhaps you could share some of that code?

Comment: I'm with Jack on this one, but I can tell you that the first error (unterminated string literal) might have something to do with strings containing single/double quotes, that delimit the string half way through. Linebreaks can cause similar issues, in some -rare- cases, try using the HEREDOC syntax, that might help

Comment: Ok, the HEREDOC Syntax is something I have not know about but seems to be an good approach, thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the strings are not escaped completely/correctly. If you take care of

- escaping all apostrophes to \'
- escaping all quotation marks to \"
- escaping all line feeds to \n

you shouldn't have any errors.